# Karate: how to pass dynamic path parameters?

Tags: cucumber-jvm, karate

Suppose I have test scenario with exact same requirements but one path variable change as follows:

Scenario: Some scenario

```
Given  path /mypath/param1
When method get
Then status 200
```

I need to run the same test for **/mypath/param2, /mypath/param3** as well.

Is there a simpler way to do it without requiring to separate the feature into a separate file and using [data driven test](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callarray/call-json-array.feature)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the [`Scenario Outline`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests) which is a standard Cucumber pattern.

```
Scenario Outline: Some scenario

Given  path /mypath/<param>
When method get
Then status 200

Examples:
| param |
| foo   |
| bar   |
```